# How can I solve an optimization problem $x^T A x$ with constraint $x^T x = 1$?

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a positive definite matrix.
>
> \begin{align}
>         &\operatorname*{minimize}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} & & x^T A x \\
>         &\text{subject to}
>         &&x^T x = 1
>         \end{align}
>
> What is the minimum which fulfills the constraints?

### My thoughts

- The constraint means that all possible solutions are on a unit sphere.
- A necessary condition (if there were no constraints) would be

$$
    \frac{\partial x^T A x}{\partial x} = 2 A x \overset{!}{=} 0
$$

- The Lagrange function is

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} (x, \lambda) &= x^T A x + \lambda (x^T x - 1)\\
\nabla_x \mathcal{L} &= \nabla_x (x^*)^T A x^* + \lambda \nabla_x ((x^*)^T x^* - 1) \\
 &= 2 \cdot A \cdot x^* + \lambda \cdot 2 \cdot x^* \overset{!}{=} 0\\
\Leftrightarrow 0 &\overset{!}{=} A \cdot x^* + x^*\\
\Leftrightarrow 0 &\overset{!}{=} (A + \lambda I) \cdot x^*\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} \mathcal{L} &= x^T x - 1 = 0 
\end{align}

I have no idea if this is correct / how to continue.

Comment: Note that you are getting the equation for the eigenvalues $(A+\lambda I)x=0$... But you know that your matrix is positive definite by assumption... Thus order the Eigenvalues from the smallest to the largest and you will be done.

Comment: Positive definite matrices have only positive Eigenvalues. Thus $\lambda > 0$? But how does this help?

Comment: Your equation $0=(A+\lambda I)x^\ast$ has a nontrivial solution ($x\neq 0$) iff $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix, and the second constraint tells us that we are only considering normed eigenvectors. So, plugging such a solution into the function $x^\top A x$ gives ${x^\ast}^\top \lambda {x^\ast}=\lambda$. Now, to minimize the function, take the smallest such lambda and you will be done.

Comment: Without the constraints, $x^TAx$ is minimized when $x=0$, which is not what you want...

Comment: @b00nheT The eigenvalue is actually $-\lambda$.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed right. I completely missed the sign.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathrm x^T \mathrm A \mathrm x \geq \lambda_{\min} (\mathrm A) \|\mathrm x\|_2^2 = \lambda_{\min} (\mathrm A) > 0$$

because $\|\mathrm x\|_2 = 1$ and $\mathrm A \succ \mathrm O$. The minimum is attained at the intersection of the eigenspace of $\lambda_{\min} (\mathrm A)$ with the unit Euclidean sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch:

- Since $A$ is positive-definite, it is symmetric and hence has an orthonormal eigenbasis.  Let $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ be the eigenvectors with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$.
- Therefore we can write $x=\sum a_iv_i$ where $\sum a_i^2=1$.  The sum condition comes from the fact that $\langle\sum a_iv_i,\sum a_iv_i\rangle=\sum a_ia_j\langle a_i,a_j\rangle=\sum a_i^2\langle a_i,a_i\rangle=\sum a_i^2$ by orthonormality.
- One can easily calculate $x^TAx$ by noting that $Ax=\sum a_i\lambda_iv_i$ and then taking the inner product as above.  This results in $\sum a_i^2\lambda_i$ by orthonormality, which is minimized/maximized when all but one $a_i$ is zero.

See also [Raleigh Quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient).

Answer (score 0):

The above approaches are correct, but just to make the link with your solution, here is another way of writing things:

$$
\begin{cases}
\nabla_x \mathcal{L} = 0\\
\nabla_{\lambda} \mathcal{L} = 0\\
\end{cases}
\quad \Rightarrow\quad
\begin{cases}
Ax = \lambda x\\
x^{T}x=1\\
\end{cases}
$$

In other words, **unitary eigenvectors** of $A$ satisfy the Lagrangian condition.

Note that the set $x^{T}x=1$ is not convex, but it is compact, so $f(x)=x^{T}Ax$ does reach its minimum on $x^{T}x=1$. So our unitary eigenvectors are definitely good candidates here.

Let $\hat{x}$ be a unitary eigenvector of $A$. It follows that 
$$
f(\hat{x})=\hat{x}^{T}A\hat{x}=\lambda x^{T}x=\lambda
$$

We can conclude that the minimum of $f$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A$, and is reached by its unitary eigenvector.